# How to protect api call from Packet Capture without SSL certification?

Tags: android

[Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en) - is app that help others to capture app network request. I can not afford SSL Certificate. So, how to protect my app from this kind of apps. I am using "POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method for api call but it can't help.

Comment: short answer is - You can't. "Packet Capture" app is the least of your worries, think about using your desktop as a hotspot that shares it's LAN over wifi, and running WireShark on that desktop. The user will literally see everything going from/to the phone if it's not using an encrypted SSL connection.

Comment: you might be better off asking this on the security forum perhaps

Comment: But i don't know android solution. So, i dont asked on the security forum.

Answer (score 1):

If you control both app and server, you can use self-signed certificate and avoid certificate issuing costs. The process is:

- create certificate yourself, there are many tools for this
- make your app trust the certificate you created - https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e

That's all. You can use HTTPS now, and all your traffic is protected from packet capture